# MySQL User Defined Variable In Select Statement As Table Name

Tags: mysql, variables, case

Can I use a User Defined Variable defined in a previous select statement as a table column in another?

Example:

```
SELECT `name`
INTO @_ptType
FROM `point_types`
WHERE `id` = _case;

SELECT SUM(@_ptType)
INTO _awardedPts
FROM `subscribers_points`
WHERE `subscriber_id` = _subscriber_id
GROUP BY `subscriber_id`;

SELECT `id`
INTO _badgeID
FROM `badges`
WHERE `trigger_point` = _awardedPts
AND `point_type_id` = _case;
```

Lets say the 'name' returned into @_ptType in the first select is 'special'

The next select should return the value of that column 'special' where sub_id, etc. match, yes?

I keep getting errors: "No data - zero rows fetched, selected, or processes"

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to create a prepared statement using a dynamic SQL string:

```
SET @sql_text = "SELECT SUM(@_ptType)
                 INTO _awardedPts
                 FROM `subscribers_points`
                 WHERE `subscriber_id` = _subscriber_id
                 GROUP BY `subscriber_id`;";

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql_text;

EXECUTE stmt;

DROP PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: I'm getting an error on my variable "_awardedPts" inside the SET stmt. Error Code: "Undeclared variable: _awardedPts"

Comment: Updated my example code, since "_awardedPts" is needed in the next select statement

Comment: Didn't pay enough attention to your code, you need to assign results to general user variables with `@varname := ...`, not into procedure variables ...